# Good choice for fast random generator in Haskell

Tags: haskell, random

I have a use-case where I want to test a program for some gambling game. The random numbers I need should be in a very small area (1 to 9), and there's no realquality needed. I found out, that the standard generator of Haskell is too slow for me, so anybody whith better ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found out about the [Xorshift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift) random gen, which perfectly suits my needs. I'm going to implement it in Haskell and put the implementation online.

It's done: [Xorshift](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xorshift-1) is uploaded to hackage, and needs some improvement by me.

Comment: Thanks for the link - I've seen similar "ergodic" pseudo-random generators before in Haskell (by using bit-shifting they can avoid the IO Monad), but hadn't seen a reference explaining the underlying theory.

Comment: FUZxxl: Glad to see the contribution - some feedback 1) This doesn't install for me.  The `build-depends` needs to be a subcatagory of library and `base` should have a range, not `-any` (use `>= 3 && < 5` if you don't have an idea).  2) There doesn't seem to be a way to get the `Int64` from `Xorshift64` (`getInt64` should have done this, yes?).  Otherwise, good work.

Comment: @TomMD: This is my very first Cabal package I ever created. No wonder that there are problems with it. I'm going to test it and upload a new version by time. If you actually want to help me, just request for push on the github repo.

Answer (score 13):

The [mersenne-random-pure64](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mersenne-random-pure64) package is very fast, as is [mwc-random](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mwc-random).