# The best choice for random number generator

Tags: haskell, random

There are so many randomizers out there. [Some](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.0.1.1) standard ones are questionably slow. [Some](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mersenne-random) claim to be of high quality and speed. [Some](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mersenne-random-pure64) claim to be of higher quality. [Some](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mwc-random-0.11.0.0) claim to be even more fast and of better quality. [Some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577146/good-choice-for-fast-random-generator-in-haskell) claim the speed but [quality](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xorshift-1).

One fact I know is that mwc-random is being used by the [Criterion](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion) benchmarking library which speaks for itself and the [claims](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mwc-random-0.11.0.0) are very promising.

Since there are at least two qualities to every generator: the robustness and the quality of the generated number - I'll split the question of choosing the best generator into three categories:

1. The fastest
2. The one generating the most random number
3. The one having the optimal combination of both of these qualities at adequate rate

So which is which and why?

Comment: I'd argue your characterization of the properties of RNGs is insufficient.  For example, you didn't define "quality" or "speed" anywhere.  Is it the fastest at producing Int's?  Floats?  Arbitrary bit strings?  Are the numbers safe to use for cryptographic/security needs?  Is it backtracking resistant?  Since all pseudo-generators will roll over eventually, what happens at roll over?

Comment: I've made minor corrections to the question, but I don't think that adding new categories (ints, floats) will help us get a good answer.

Comment: I don't think (3) is answerable with the information you've given, as that depends on what you are using it for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I only can speak about mwc-random.

1. It is fast ~15ns per Word32 on Phenom II. If you want to measure how fast is it on your computer it comes with benchmark set. Still it possible to trade period for speed. Xorshift RNG should be faster but have shorter periods 2^32 or 2^64 instead of 2^8222.
2. Randomness. mwc-random uses algorithm MWC256 (another name: MWC8222) which is not cryptographicaly secure but fares well in randomness tests. In particular mwc-random passes [dieharder randomness test](http://www.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/General/dieharder.php).