# Fastest way to generate a billion random doubles in Haskell

Tags: performance, haskell, random

I'm doing Monte-Carlo simulations, and currently using `System.Random`.

```hs
import System.Random
main = do
  g <- newStdGen
  let xs = randoms g :: [Double]
  -- normally, I'd do other magic here
  putStrLn $ show $ length $ take 10^9 xs
```

Unfortunately, this takes a really long time, at least 5x slower than Python's `random.random()`, to say nothing of the C `rand()` call.

With `ghc -O2 -optc-ffast-math -optc-O3`

```
import System.Random
main = do
  g <- newStdGen
  let xs = randoms h :: [Double]
  putStrLn $ show $ length $ take (10^7) xs
```

takes ~8s vs. (in iPython)

```
import random
%timeit len([random.random() for _ in range(10 ** 7)])
```

takes ~1.3s. My goal is one billion, but Haskell cannot generate them in a reasonable amount of time.

I also have a C++ program that generates floats with `rand()`. It does `10^7` samples in 0.2s.

**How can I generate random doubles in the range `[0-1)` quickly in Haskell?**

Ideally, the program GHC generates will just blast `rand()` POSIX calls and collect into a list. The answer with the cleanest & fastest code wins. (No, having 10x the code for 1% speedup isn't worth it.)

Comment: check out [System.Random.MWC](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mwc-random)

Comment: @user5402 Using MWC's example of `withSystemRandom . asGenST $ \gen -> uniformVector gen (10^7)` to generate a `Vector` (which should be more efficient) of 10 million doubles, it took about 15 seconds on my computer, while using `System.Random.randoms` took only 12.5 seconds.  Are you sure this will really speed up the generation?

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577146/good-choice-for-fast-random-generator-in-haskell

Comment: @Sibi `random-mwc` may be helpful, but bheklilr's results make me seem less eager to try. Anything with a Mersenne algorithm is going for quality over speed (and the library only claims a 2-4x speedup over `System.Random`). I'll look into `Xorshift` but I don't know how to use it yet. (reading the source...)

Comment: Don't benchmark using GHCi.  Compile the code and use `-O2 -fllvm`.  Do not add debugging flags.

Comment: The MWC package of choice (for me) is mersenne-random-pure64.  This clocks in about 10x faster than the `random` package (0.12 seconds for 10^6 doubles) and has better quality in its randomness.

Comment: @PythonNut The Mersenne algorithm may have decent statistical properties, but it's incredibly easy to predict the entire future sequence from a few data points.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson `-fllvm` is broken on `LLVM 3.5+`. See edited post.

Comment: ... So why didn't you try the mwc package I suggested and get down around 0.8 seconds?  Also, if you want c rand() then just use ffi.  Finally, if you are OK with IO and have RDRAND then that will probably blow away everything else.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson because I don't have Haskell with me. I just pasted the result of a previous run. (I did a _lot_ of running and timing) I'll get to it.

Comment: @PythonNut this discussion is a little confusing. To clarify things, here is the sort of Haskell module people were talking about above: http://sprunge.us/UOjE together with the compilation instructions and timings for 10 ^ 7. It seems to be at least 10 x as fast as the Python -- with `--fllvm` almost 20x as fast. I'm not sure what instructions @bheklilr was giving the compiler. `System.Random` is not appropriate for this task, and doesn't really mean the same as the python, as the infinite list you define might suggest.

Comment: mwc isn't a Mersenne twister, it's an xorshift.  There are some similarities, but they're not the same.  Also I'm skeptical of @bheklilr's results; System.Random is known to be quite slow and there are several much faster libraries available.

Comment: @JohnL is certainly possible that I messed up the example, but I literally copy/pasted from the documentation. Those were the numbers I saw. Yes, I was yang GHCi to do this, but I don't thing there would be that huge of a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's Mersenne which surprisingly seemed to be faster than MWC and beats C++ although we are on different computers ;-). It's tempting to see how much parallelising it would buy but I had better go back to work.

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall                      #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-warn-name-shadowing   #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-warn-type-defaults    #-}

import System.Random.Mersenne.Pure64

testUniform :: Int -> Double -> PureMT -> Double
testUniform 0 !x _ = x
testUniform n !x gen =
    testUniform (n - 1) (x + y) gen'
  where
    (y, gen') = randomDouble gen

n :: Int
n = 10^7

total :: Double
total = testUniform n 0 (pureMT $ fromIntegral arbSeed)

arbSeed :: Int
arbSeed = 8

mean :: Double
mean = total / fromIntegral n

main :: IO ()
main = print mean

~/Dropbox/Private/Stochastic $ ./MersennePure +RTS -s
0.4999607889729769
     802,924,992 bytes allocated in the heap
         164,240 bytes copied during GC
          44,312 bytes maximum residency (2 sample(s))
          21,224 bytes maximum slop
               1 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                    Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0      1634 colls,     0 par    0.00s    0.01s     0.0000s    0.0000s
  Gen  1         2 colls,     0 par    0.00s    0.00s     0.0001s    0.0002s

  INIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  MUT     time    0.11s  (  0.11s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.00s  (  0.01s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  Total   time    0.12s  (  0.12s elapsed)

  %GC     time       4.2%  (5.4% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    7,336,065,126 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  95.7% of total user, 93.5% of total elapsed
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is more or less like PythonNut's use case, but it is worth noting you are saving significantly by avoiding construction then traversal of a large list.

Comment: Sorry, I'm currently unable to install packages so I can't answer... :(

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson wouldn't Stream Fusion nullify that overhead?

Comment: 1. Lists use [foldr/build](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/915) and not stream fusion. 2. The elimination of intermediate data structures depends on the use, which is why this example could be more (or less) like your use but we have insufficient information.

Comment: @Dominic Steinitz, this worked very well. You're Haskell beats my C++ because my C++ is actual doing some (relatively) expansive computations. In any case, this got me to about ~1.5x C++ which makes me happy.